# Puppeteer: Clicking button on a website doesn't work

Tags: forms, button, puppeteer

I'm trying to find the corresponding code for puppeteer to automate a button press.

In a userscript it can be done easily via

```
document.getElementsByClassName("details-cart-button btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg d-flex justify-content-center tp-button ")[0].click();
```

However im struggling to replicate the same behavior using puppeteer.

What I tried so far:

```
//Try 1:
await page.click('a[class="details-cart-button btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg d-flex justify-content-center tp-button "]');

//Try 2:
await page.$eval('a[class^="details-cart-button"]', el => el.click());

//Try3: 
const form = await page.$('id#add-to-cart-form');
await form.evaluate( form => form.click() );

//Try4: 
await Promise.all([
await page.click('#add-to-cart-form > a.details-cart-button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.btn-lg.d-flex.justify-content-center.tp-button')
]);
```

None of the methods seem to work sadly and I have no idea how to get it done.

Could someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have not tested the selectors, but the code looks correct.  Could you add a little more about your test setup?  Are you sure puppeteer is correctly accessing the page?  There is a Cookies/Tracking popup that needs to be dealt with on that page.  Screenshots are helpful (e.g., `await page.screenshot({path: 'test1.png'});`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async ()=>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto('https://www.alternate.de/html/product/1685585');

 
  const acceptCookiesSelector='button[class="cookie-submit-all"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(acceptCookiesSelector);
  await page.click(acceptCookiesSelector);

  const buySelector='a[class="details-cart-button btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg d-flex justify-content-center tp-button "]';
  await page.waitForSelector(buySelector);
  await page.click(buySelector);

})();
```

I will try to explain why your code didn't work.

The click method that you use on the page scrolls into view the element that you want to click and uses the left mouse button and clicks on it, in your case, the button was in the view, but it was overshadowed by the accept-cookie banner, so all you have to do is click on accept the cookies to get rid of that banner then click on the buy button and it will work.

Your first example worked because click method in the browser console is a different method than the one used on Puppeteer, and it worked because it doesn't rely on the mouse to generate the click.